# How do I use multisig transactions?

Tags: security, multi-signature

I want to create an joint "address", made of 3 individual ordinary addresses, such that any combination of 2 addresses can move the bitcoins stored at the joint address.

What is the way to do this using current tooling? Please be as detailed as possible, specify tools, specific command line argument, etc.

1. How do I create the 3 addresses? (They should each be created on a separate computer, to increase security)
2. How do I send money to the joint address?
3. How do I spend money from the joint address?

Comment: @eMansipater - now it does.